# How to get df2 in causality() Granger test in R

Tags: r, time-series

I use a VAR(1) model with two variables (f,m) each with 59 observations; 
I already saw R help and several books about this topic but can't figure how `df2 = 108`.

```
library(vars)
var.causal.m <- causality(ajustVAR1FM, cause = "m")
> var.causal.m
$Granger

    Granger causality H0: m do not Granger-cause f

data:  VAR object ajustVAR1FM 
F-Test = 5.9262, df1 = 1, df2 = 108, p-value = 0.01656
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the package [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vars.pdf),  it is clearly written that the test is distributed as `F(pK1k2, KT-n*)` where K=k1+k2 and n* equal to the total number of parameters in the above VAR(p) (including deterministic regressors). Further, for the test, the vector of endogenous variables yt is split into two subvectors y1t and y2t with dimensions (K1×1) and (K2×1) with K=K1+K2.

You can also type `causality` in console and see the following:

```
df1 <- p * length(y1.names) * length(y2.names)
  df2 <- K * obs - length(PI)
```

Example: using Canada data

```
library(vars)
var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const") 
causality(var.2c, cause = "e") 
> dim(Canada)
[1] 84  4



Causality(var.2c, cause = "e")
$Granger

Granger causality H0: e do not Granger-cause prod rw U

data:  VAR object var.2c 
F-Test = 6.2768, df1 = 6, df2 = 292, p-value = 3.206e-06
```

Cause variable is 1 so k1=1, k2=3 (4-1) where 4 is total number of variables, T is the effective number of observations (here 84-2(lag=2))=82, n*=36 (4 equations with 9 parameters each). So, df1=2*1*3=6 and df2=4*82-36=292

Note: 
In your case lag p=1,n*=8 (you estimate two models with 4 parameters in each (I suspect you also have trend so it should be 4),obs (effective 59-1 (lag p=1)) = 58, k1=1 , k2=1 and K=2. So, df1=1*1*1=1 and df2=2*58-8=108.